# how to redirect output of echo over ssh to a file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to redirect content of a variable to a file through ssh. like:

```
ssh $MachineIP  echo $CM_Config > $mName/CM_CONFIG
```

where `$CM_Config` is a local variable in my host containing multiple line, and `$mName/CM_CONFIG` is located in `$MachineIP` 
how should I redirect local variable to the remote file assuming my ssh configurations are correct.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case the problem solved with this command:

```
ssh $MachineIP " echo \"$CM_Config\" > \"$mName/CM_CONFIG\" "
```

In fact without \" enclosing my variable, my problem didn't solved. Maybe it is because that the content of these variables are somehow like bash command and are in multiple lines.

Answer (score 9):

You must quote the whole command with double quotes

```
ssh $MachineIP "echo $CM_Config > $mName/CM_CONFIG"
```

This allows the variables to be replaced by the local shell and the redirection done at the remote host.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but I found the exact correct answer somewhere else.